# Do I need another views file for my classes?

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to make a calendar application. So I would need to make some classes to display the calendar and add events to it. Do those classes still go in my views file or do I have to make a separate directory and import it to my views file and make then make an instance of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people put view classes into the views.py file.

If it becomes unmanageable or you need further organization, split them as necessary.

You don't need to import it into views.py - they are ultimately only used by the `urls.py` which don't require views live in any particular place.

If you're talking about application logic, if it's a huge class that's not necessarily related to the web HTTP response cycle, then it makes sense to place it in another file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am talking about application logic. So you mean I have to make a separate directory something like library and put my application logic there?

Comment: It's up to you. I don't go as far as a directory unless I have a reason to such as.. 4x different payment backends in a directory called backends. If it logically fits in one file, I don't see what's wrong with putting it next to the views.py file.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your answer!